# trouble whit Pthreads while compiling Darwin media streaming server in ubuntu 14,04

Tags: bash, ubuntu, gcc, pthreads, darwin

Hi I'm trying to install Darwin media streaming server version 6.0.3 on Ubuntu 14.04.
I've got errors like this when I tried to execute bash file named "Buildit" file.

undefined reference to `pthread_mutexattr_init'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [QTFileInfo] Error 1

all errors are about Pthreads it seems my gcc has problem with this.
gcc version : 4.9.2 (Ubuntu 4.9.2-0ubuntu1~14.04)

I can compile some simple Pthread codes without any problem!
Does this version of Darwin server requires any specific version of gcc ?
help please :)

Comment: I am assuming you are passing -pthread option to gcc, correct?

Comment: yes :) but still I have errors

Answer (score 0):

When you build Darwin Streaming Server,
you may see some error messages about pthread library.

a) Open Buildit

b) Find a code section for your platform (ex: Linux.X86_64)

c) Change CORE_LINK_LIBS = "...." and change it to
CORE_LINK_LIBS="-lstdc++ -lm -lcrypt -ldl -lpthread"

Got it at https://www.mail-archive.com/cloudsuite@listes.epfl.ch/msg00187.html